# Loading labelled imagess in ITK-SNAP for rendering

Tags: mesh, vtk, itk, medical

I am trying to get a mesh of the cerebellum. The issue is that the mri volume does not have a high enough resolution to enable a reliable identification of different substructures so what i am doing is parsing svg files of delineations of histological staining slides and converting them into filled masks kind of what you would get after using polygon tool on one slice of the mri volume. I do this for around 20 slices.

Can i load a labelled volume in snap where each voxel is labelled with an id corresponding to some structure and each structure has its own rgb color code kind of like the load label feature. When i load this volume into snap will snap recognize the labelled voxels and allow me use interpolate label features for interpolating these labels to unlabelled slices and then do a export mesh. Right now what im doing is

```
import nibabel as nib
import numpy as np

d3 = fixed_3d.astype("int16")
d3[210,:,:][ind] = 1 # ind is the coords inside my structure
new_image = nib.Nifti1Image(d3, affine=np.eye(4))
nib.save(new_image, "vol.nii.gz")
```

fixed_3d is my atlas volume then i load this in itk snap and also do a import label . my label file looks like

IDX   -R-  -G-  -B-  -A--  VIS MSH     LABEL

```
0     0    0    0  0.00    0    0    "Clear" 

1    48  126  110  1.00    1    1    "arb"
```

But when i click on export as surface mesh i get the message missing mesh for selected label

Comment: The question is unclear. For example, what's a "provision in snap"? Check your English carefully, let us know if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a step of registering histology slides to MR image. Otherwise your workflow looks good.

Comment: yeah i do that i register the histology images to the mr images. This is my workflow1. Get the bounded region in the original image from the svg file 
2. Resize the original image, get the bounded region in the new image
3. Fill it in, use numpy.where to find all the coordinates inside the image
4. Register the resized image to the reference atlas, store the transform
5. Apply this transform to the points obtained from 3, to find the new set of points in the reference atlas 
6. Assign labels to these voxels from the label file.
7. Load in ITK-SNAP and press export as surface mesh

Comment: but the issue right now is , when i read the .mhd file which is the volumetric file, it contains integers in the voxels how do i make sure that when i label the structures relevant for my structures those will be the only voxels with that label also when i save this new volume as .nii or .mha or .mhd snap complains that they are 32 bit precision and not 16 and i just see a black screen is there some way to do the labelling and load this new file in snap

Comment: hey thanks can you help me with this bit my understanding is that snap labels voxels belonging to a structure with the same integer so if i provide a labelled image will snap recognize it also how do i ensure that other voxels in my image dont have that same label

Comment: i think i got it i have to load the labelled mask in open segmentation tab and it has values only in the valid region